# user input to create java program

Tags: java

I've tried creating codes to solve a quadratic formula but I've only succeeded in creating it for a specific formula. Is there any way I can be providing the variables `a`, `b`, `c` by user input then the solution prints out? The program also refuses to run on command prompt but can run in eclipse. What might be the issue?

Here it is.

```
public class Equationsolver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a, b, c;
    a = 2;
    b = 6;
    c = 4;

    double disc = Math.pow(b,2) - 4*a*c;
    double soln1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(disc)) / (2*a) ;
    double soln2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(disc)) / (2*a);
    if (disc >= 0) {
        System.out.println("soln1 = " + soln1);
        System.out.println("soln2 = " + soln2);
    }else{
        System.out.println("equation has no real roots");
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: 1. did you compile? 2. did you add the directory with the .class files to the classpath? if either is false there is the issue

Comment: I've done all that. but my main issue is the user input for the variables. Right now I can only change the variables in the eclipse rather than in the output. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is just me being picky, but you should calculate disc THEN do a check on whether it's GEQ 0. If it is then calculate soln1 and soln2 and then print accordingly. You're doing unnecessary computations if disc is LT 0.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility to take user input is to use the paramater `String [] args`.
The `String [] args` contains the value pass to the program when you executed it like `java -jar program.jar arg1 arg2 arg3`.

In your case, you will need to check if the user pass 3 arguments to the program and if so then assigned thoses values to your variables.

Here is a little bit of code that might help, note that I didn't add the validation and you will need more validation to make sure that you sanitize the user input:

```
public class Equationsolver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a, b, c;
    a = Double.parseDouble(args[0]); //Here it will get the first argument pass to the program
    b = Double.parseDouble(args[1]); 
    c = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);

    double disc = Math.pow(b,2) - 4*a*c;
    double soln1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(disc)) / (2*a) ;
    double soln2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(disc)) / (2*a);
    if (disc >= 0) {
        System.out.println("soln1 = " + soln1);
        System.out.println("soln2 = " + soln2);
    }else{
        System.out.println("equation has no real roots");
    }

    }

}
```

EDIT: You will probably need to change your code to adapt to the fact that now `a` `b` and `c` might not be what you were thinking.

Answer (score 3):

You can take dynamic inputs from users in following way too

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
double a = in.nextDouble();
double b = in.nextDouble();
double c = in.nextDouble();
```